# Appendix header

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I'm trying to format a template for my thesis appendix and am having an issue which is doing my head in. I want my appendices to have a header saying Appendix A - "Title of appendix chapter". Or alternative just "Title of appendix chapter"
This is working for My first appendix chapter, but my second chapter also displays Appendix A - "second appendix chapter title" despite the chapter title saying Appendix B.

The code below is a hash, but this was the only option I could find that actually turned the heading into Appendix rather than Chapter A, Chapter B etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{appendices}  
\appendixpage  
\appendix  
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Appendix \thechapter     \  -- \leftmark}  
\input{Appendix1}  
\input{Appendix2}  
\end{appendices}  
\end{document}
```

Where Appendix chapters start with:

```
\chapter{Example title 1}  
Appendix text.
```

I'm most happy keeping my Appendix chapters separate and using `\input`, but flexible about the rest of it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! How are the headers for ordinary chapters defined?

Comment: \pagestyle{fancy}  
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }  
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}  
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Chapter \thechapter     \  -- \leftmark}  
\fancyfoot{}  
\input{Litreview/Litreview.tex}  %First chapter

Comment: I have no such problem with your code.

Comment: I've just had a play and its always the last chapter of my appendices that reverts to saying Appendix A-Title..

Comment: Ther must be something else than the simple code you poste. For me, appendix B  *is* appendix B in the header.

Comment: Ok, thanks Bernard. I have a lot of packages installed for other parts of the thesis so maybe there is a mismatch there somewhere. The code for the appendix section is exactly as above.

Comment: The best thing to do is to comment the unnecessary (for the appendix) packages, and gradually uncomment them until the error reappears, in order to find the culprit.

Comment: Genius! Found the issue in the \pagestyle{fancy} command above my main chapters.   \mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Chapter \thechapter     \  -- \leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
%\input{Litreview/Litreview.tex}
\input{Methods/Methods.tex}

\begin{appendices}
\appendixpage  
\appendix  
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Appendix \thechapter     \  -- \leftmark}  
\input{Appendices/Appendix1}  
\input{Appendices/Appendix1}
\input{Appendices/Appendix1}  
\end{appendices}

Comment: But that command determines the formatting I want in my main chapters. Can I turn that off when I get to my appendix?

Comment: All's well that ends well… Note that `titlesec` defines a `\chaptertitlename` which defaults to `\chaptername` in ordinary chapters, and to `\appendixname` after `\appendix`.

Comment: Thanks Bernard, without using titlesec can I stop the \pagestyle{fancy} command in the appendix? I need it for previous chapters.

Comment: If you have no ‘normal’ chapters after the appendices, you can use this (keeping `\pagestyle{fancy}`): `\usepackage{ apptools}
\AtAppendix{\let\chaptername\appendixname}`.

Comment: the command `\@chapapp` expand to Chapter in main text and to Appendix in appendix text so yo only need to replace `\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Chapter \thechapter \ -- \leftmark}` with `\makeatletter
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ -- \leftmark}
\makeatother`

Comment: Is there any news here? I couldn't really follow.

Comment: @Bernard Do you want to write an answer?